# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^1\frac1{(1+x^3)^{n}}dx$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integration-by-parts

I proved the part of the equation which asked for
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\cdot (1+x^3)^{-n} \right]=-(3n-1)\cdot (1+x^3)^{-n}+3n\cdot (1+x^3)^{-n-1}
$$ **d/dx[x(1+x)−nx(1+x)−n]= another equation**. However, the last part, relating to **I_n**, is quite difficult to prove. I tried doing it with Integration by parts but never reached closer to the answer.
Hope you provide with the full solution for the last part of the question highlighted as **(i)**. Thank you! The link to the picture's below.
P.S. I am learning MathJax formatting that's why I uploaded a picture. Hope you understand.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfKt5.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We set
$$
I_n:=\int_0^1\frac1{(1+x^3)^{n}}dx.
$$

**Hint**. You have already proved that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\cdot (1+x^3)^{-n} \right]=-(3n-1)\cdot (1+x^3)^{-n}+3n\cdot (1+x^3)^{-n-1}
$$ then integrating from $0$ to $1$ gives
$$
\int_0^1\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\cdot (1+x^3)^{-n} \right]\right)dx=-(3n-1)\cdot \int_0^1(1+x^3)^{-n}dx+3n\cdot \int_0^1(1+x^3)^{-n-1}dx
$$ or$$
\underbrace{\int_0^1\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left[x\cdot (1+x^3)^{-n} \right]\right)dx}_{\Large\color{red}{?}}=-(3n-1)\cdot I_n+3n\cdot I_{n+1}
$$ Can you finish it?

Comment: Oh Thank you very much @Olivier Oloa I just noticed that I was writing **I_(n+1)** as **I_(n-1)**. Once again, thank you very much for the answer. I can finally move ahead!

Comment: @LordAbys007 You are welcome!